TimeoutError: The write operation timed out (using google gemini) - SOLVED
PROBLEM SOLVED: IT WAS A NETWORK ERROR
I am getting an error using google gemini apis (I think that's because of the file size, but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to fix it).
My current location is Italy, and I got APIs using a VPN.
When uploading small audio files, I have no problem, but uploading bigger ones gives me some errors.
I first tried with my local wifi, and got this error (also using ethernet):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matte\Desktop\gemini.py", line 37, in <module>
    audioFile = genai.upload_file(path = filePath, display_name = "audio_file")
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\generativeai\files.py", line 52, in upload_file    
    response = client.create_file(
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\generativeai\client.py", line 74, in create_file   
    result = request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 922, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 221, in _retry_request     
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 190, in _retry_request     
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1364, in _conn_request        
    conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1276, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1322, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1271, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1070, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 992, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1236, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1205, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
TimeoutError: The write operation timed out

My wifi speed is about 25 Mb in download and 3 Mb in upload.
Then I tried using hotspot with my cellphone (about 30 Mb in download and 8 Mb in upload), and I get this different error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\matte\Desktop\gemini.py", line 55, in <module>
    audioFile = genai.upload_file(path = path, display_name = "audio_file")
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\generativeai\files.py", line 52, in upload_file
    response = client.create_file(
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\google\generativeai\client.py", line 74, in create_file
    result = request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 131, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\matte\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 937, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/upload/v1beta/files?key=MY_API_KEY&alt=json&uploadType=multipart returned "User location is not supported for the API use.". Details: "User location is not supported for the API use.">

It seems like I cannot use APIs because I'm in Europe, but the problem only raises when I use my hotspot. I also checked using a smaller file with this network, and gives the same error, while with my local wifi (with smaller files, like 5/10 minutes of audio) everything is ok: the error cited before only occurs when trying to upload 40/50 minutes-long audios, but I saw on Gemini’s website it should be able to use up to 9 hours-long audios (I'm using gemini pro 1.5).
Here is my code:
import google.generativeai as genai

genai.configure(api_key=MY_API_KEY)
filePath = AUDIO_FILE_PATH

generation_config = {
  "temperature": 1,
  "top_p": 0.95,
  "top_k": 0,
  "max_output_tokens": 8192,
}

safety_settings = [
  {
    "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HARASSMENT",
    "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"
  },
  {
    "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_HATE_SPEECH",
    "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"
  },
  {
    "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_SEXUALLY_EXPLICIT",
    "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"
  },
  {
    "category": "HARM_CATEGORY_DANGEROUS_CONTENT",
    "threshold": "BLOCK_NONE"
  },
]


audioFile = genai.upload_file(path = filePath, display_name = "audio_file")


model = genai.GenerativeModel(model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-latest",
                              generation_config=generation_config,
                              safety_settings=safety_settings)

response = model.generate_content(["summarize this audio", audioFile])
print(response.text)

P.S. I removed an error I had put before as I noticed it occurred because the file extension was not supported (I used an .m4a file, and in Gemini's website it's not written as a supported filetype).


My guess is you have a local network problem. Where are you running this code? Edit the question on the network the application is using to communicate with Gemini. 2) What is the size of the object you are trying to upload? Try again with a small audio file.



In your last edit, you removed details about the error. That information provides details on where in the SSL code the error happened. I do not recommend removing that information. 2) You added information about your network. That information is not useful. Provide details on country, Internet type (fiber, DSL, etc), modem type, computer connection type (Ethernet, Wifi), speed, other network tests that you performed, etc. 3) You might have two problems to solve: a) network failure (stability, speed) and b) audio file size.


With your last update, I am confident you have a local network problem. Develop your application using a local system with a stable fast Internet connection. Once everything is working and you have good debug code and logging as part of your application, then test on public networks. Some public Wifi setups will not allow you to upload large files over their connection. That would explain why the connection is being reset.
